# onClick echo PHP code to div (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So what I'm trying to do is the following:

first: When the button `add-location` is clicked this loads a php file using AJAX.

**jQuery**

```
$('.add-location').click(function() {
        var locationName = $(this).data('location');
            $.post('http://www.example.com/reload-location-2.php?addparam',
            {locationName: locationName}, function(data) {
                $("textarea#location").html(data);
        })
    });
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php start_session();
$locationName = array_key_exists('locationName', 
$_POST) ? (string) $_POST['locationName'] : '';

   if(isset($_GET['delparam'])){
       unset($_SESSION['locations'][$locationName]);
   }

   if(isset($_GET['addparam'])){
    $_SESSION['locations'][$locationName] = $locationName;
   }
?>

<?php foreach ($_SESSION['locations'] as $location): ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($location); echo "\n"; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

This all works like a charm! No worries here. No what I'm trying to do is when the button `add-location` is clicked this `echo's` the following code to a `div` called `textarea#thema`.

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); echo "\n"; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

OR, if that's easier when the page is loaded -> echo that code to the `textarea#thema` div.

I do not understand AJAX that much but I'm getting there. But I think the last option maybe the easiest solution?

Could anyone help me figure this one out?

---

**What I tried**

Right now, When the button `add-location` is clicked I reload a previous jQuery script:

```
$('.add-location').click(function() {
        var productName = $(this).data('product');
            $.post('http://example.com/reload-2.php?addparam',
            {productName: productName}, function(data) {
                $("textarea#thema").html(data);
        })
    });
```

This works, but it adds an extra `<p>`-tag leaving me with a line break in the code.

I also changed the `.html(data);` to `.val(data);` for the textareas. Also I made a new PHP file with just this code:

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); echo "\n"; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
 $('.add-location').click(function() {
            var productName = $(this).data('product');
                $.post('http://www.example.com/reload-3.php', 
                {productName: productName}, function(data) {
                   $("textarea#thema").val(data);
            })
        });
```

But still no go... And I don't think this is the way to go?? I hope I gave enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.val()` function to fill textarea, not `.html()`.

Comment: Nope. @Hulothe. the line break is still there when using `.val();`

Comment: are you sure the line break isn't from the '\n' you're echoing?

Comment: @Cruiser, Jeeezzz I feel so stupid! I made the reload-3 so that it didn't use `"\n"` and now the line break is gone. Maybe it was also to do with the `.val();` and not `.html();`. Well thanks for this.